# How can this problem be solved using the ratio test?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would you solve sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2-5n-5}$ using the ratio test?

Comment: You want to *solve* it (know the exact value), or know if it converges?

Comment: Both. meaning that if it does converge, what is the number and if it diverges, what does it diverge to?

Comment: The [Term test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) is enoguh, then. I asked you that because I didn't understand your question, *how would you solve a sum with a convergence test*?

Comment: Thats what I was confused about. The wording on the home work from my professor is not the best. Thank you I just solved it another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use ratio test it will tell you nothing, instead try looking at the limit of the sequence $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{n^{2}}{n^{2}-5n -5}=?$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Use comparison test on the sequence you are summing over with the sequence $\frac{n^2}{n^2} = 1$.  Think $n$-th term test.